# Can I force template type to have CTOR with certain signature?

Tags: c#, generics

Can I force template type to have CTOR with certain signature?

For Example:

```
class cSilSingleton<T> where T: class, new(),new(object[])
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: no, you can't. there is no such constraint exist.if you explain why you need this we may be able to help you better.

Comment: It would be nice if we could have our complete visions coded in a shortcut, but sadly our fingers are still required today.